# Indexing into type 'com.ItemBean' is not supported

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a wrapper class like so:

```
@NoArgsConstructor 
@Data 
public class ListWrapper {

    public ListWrapper(List<Object> objects) {

        this.objects = objects;
    }

    private List<Object> objects;

}
```

I am looking to populate the wrapper with custom beans.  Let's call it an ItemBean.

So then I have:

```
@GetMapping("/rentSetup")
public String setupRent(@RequestParam("companyId") Integer companyId,
                        Model model) {

    List<Object> beans = new ArrayList<>();
    ItemBean bean = new Builder()
                .someProperty(something)
                .build();
    beans.add(bean);

    ListWrapper wrapper = new ListWrapper(beans);
    model.addAttribute("itemBeansWrapper", wrapper);
    return "setup";
}
```

I'd like to have the user edit the property `someProperty` on in the view.  I'm thinking that I would do:

```
<form th:object="${itemBeansWrapper}"
      th:action="@{/setup(companyId=${companyId})}"
      th:method="post">

    <div th:each="bean, iterStat : ${itemBeansWrapper.objects}">
      <input type="number"
             th:name="${bean[__${iterStat.index}__].someProperty}">
    </div>

    <button type="submit"
            th:name="action"
            th:value="review" value="review"> Review
    </button>
</form>
```

But this results in:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1027E:(pos 4): Indexing into type 'com.ItemBean' is not supported
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.Indexer.getValueRef(Indexer.java:176)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note that I also have my controller annotated with `@SessionAttributes({"companyId", "itemBeansWrapper"})` since I would like to persist the wrapper across pages in the session.

If I leave off the `[__${iterStat.index}__]`, the page compiles fine, but I am thinking that I would need something like that to differentiate the nested beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caught my error.  It should be:

```
<input type="number" th:field="*{objects[__${iterStat.index}__].someProperty}"/>
```